# Nebular's dropdown does not scroll with the page

Tags: angular, autocomplete, nebular

I'm trying to implement a auto complete, dropdown element, in an angular app. The auto complete works just fine but when I scroll down, on the page, the auto complete does not scroll up with the page. The image below depict my scenario. The left side shows when I start typing and the right side shows when I scroll down on the page:

[image: auto complete scroll image, not working]

The correct behavior should show that the auto complete dropdown element should be positioned fixed right below the input element. I've used [this nebular NbAutocompleteDirective](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/autocomplete/examples#nbautocompletedirective).

I've tried to set the parent container's position to relative but that also did not work. Does anyone have a resolution to this problem?

Here is a screenshot of the nebular version I'm using (incase it's relevant):

[image: angular and nebular version - screenshot]

Comment: It is better if you make a sample of this problem in the Stackblitz and provide the link.

Answer (score 0):

I went with [angular-ng-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-ng-autocomplete)

It's much better.